# After I installed my Go in my macbook, how can I find the place of it?

Tags: macos, go, homebrew

After I use :

```
brew install go
```

Installed my Go in my mac, and it give a Summary:

```
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.8.1: 7,030 files, 281.8MB
```

But in my finder I can not find the `local` directory.

[image]

How to find my installed Go library in my mac?

Comment: In terminal, are you able to go to that directory(cd /usr/local) ?

Comment: @Girdhar Sojitra yes, I can, but why my finder did not show that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All threads like [this one](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1542705?tstart=0) point out that:

> This directory is hidden as it's a system directory and users have no need to change anything in it.
>
> To expose it in finder enter <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> in finder and in the resulting popup enter

```
/usr/local
```

Comment: Note this answer won’t work if one installed Homebrew somewhere else than in `/usr/local`. See my answer for a general solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `prefix` of any Homebrew formula with `brew --prefix <formula>`. Even if the formula isn’t installed it’ll show where it’d be if it were.

```
$ brew --prefix go
/usr/local/opt/go
```

You can open any directory in the Finder from your terminal using `open`, so all you have to do is:

```
open $(brew --prefix go)
```

Comment: I agree. +1. I was only addressing the visibility of `/usr/local` through the finder.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at this https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5418731?tstart=0

Choose Go to Folder from the Finder's Go menu and provide /usr/local/ as the path.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that should be noted is that, based on the attached image, you were looking in your /User folder which is not the same as /usr.